# How to extract the indices of alternate nodes in a graph

Tags: matlab, graph, nodes

I have the following graph created using the commands in MATLAB,

```
tail = [1 2 3 4 5 6 6 7 8 9 10  12 13 14 15];
head = [2 3 4 5 6 7 12 8 9 10 11 13 14 15 16];
NodeLabel = string(1:16)';
EdgeLabel = strcat(string(tail),string(head));
Graph = graph(tail,head)
Graph.Nodes.Name = cellstr(NodeLabel);
```

I want to extract the indices of alternate nodes. For a graph without branches, I can obtain the positions of alternate nodes from `Graph.Nodes.Name` by using a step size of two. Since the above graph has two branches, I am not sure how to do this.

The desired output is,

AlternateNodes = [1 3 5 7 9 11 12 14 16]

I would like to ask for suggestions on how to obtain the indices of alternate nodes from a branched graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the given graph this is possible with the shortestpath function. First you can identify the head nodes and tail nodes of the graph by:

```
hNodes = setdiff(tail, head);
tNodes = setdiff(head, tail);
```

For simplicity here I'm going to assume your two paths are from node 1 to nodes 11 and 16. You could expand on this as needed by modifying the next block of code to loop over hNodes or tNodes.

You can use shortestpath to get the list of nodes along each of the branching paths. A setdiff call is used to find the nodes that belong only to the second branch. You can then get your desired results by taking every other node in path1, and then appending every other node from the second branch

```
path1 = shortestpath(Graph, 1, 11);
path2 = shortestpath(Graph, 1, 16);
branch2 = setdiff(path2, path1); 
AlternateNodes = [path1(1:2:end) branch2(1:2:end)]

AlternateNodes =

    1     3     5     7     9    11    12    14    16
```